# Inserting and Retrieving array data using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to insert and retrieve array data using ajax in Codeigniter, I tried below code doesn't work anyone can tell me a solution.

```
$('#click').click(function(){
          var selected = new Array();
          $(".stafftable input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
          selected.push(this.value);
          });
          var selected_member_id=localStorage.getItem('selectids');
          var myarray=selected_member_id.split(','); // convert string to an array
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Welcome/send_to_staff", 
            data: {staff_id:selected,members_id:myarray},

                  success: 
                  function(data)
                      {
                         if(data==true){
                            // localStorage.clear();
                            load_unseen_notification();
                          }
                          else{
                            alert("localstorage not cleared");
                          }

                      }
            });
    });
```

In Controller 
but I tried this below code but didn't insert to a database table

```
public function send_to_staff(){

            $staff_id=$this->input->post('staff_id'); 
            $membersids[]= $this->input->post('members_id');
            $members_id=json_encode($membersids);

            if($staff_id !==''){  
                $data['staff_id']=$staff_id;
                $data['members_id']=$members_id;
                 $inserted=$this->db->insert('ag_matched_members',$data); // insert query
                if($inserted == true){
                    echo true;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo false;
                }

            }

}
```

Comment: what comes in `$staff_id` and `$members_id`?

Comment: The url in your ajax call ``` url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Welcome/send_to_staff",  ``` should not contain capital W it should be ``` url:"<?php echo base_url('welcome/send_to_staff');?>" ``` , try and check

Comment: $staff_id and $members_id new variables and posted data assign to those variables

Comment: What error you get? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Also have you checked ajax requets in Netwrok Tab, does it sends all data to server?

Comment: didn't show any error

Comment: Does it send all data have you checked in network tab?

Comment: url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Welcome/send_to_staff its working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make changes like this in your code. hope it works.

```
$('#click').click(function(){
            var selected = new Array(); //assigning array to variable

        $(".stafftable input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
          selected.push(this.value);
          });
       var selected_member_id=localStorage.getItem('selectids');
          var string_selected=selected.toString(); //converting array to string

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Welcome/send_to_staff", 
                data: {staff_id:string_selected,members_id:selected_member_id}, //string selected

                      success: 
                      function(data)
                          {

                             if(data==true){
                                // localStorage.clear();
                                load_unseen_notification();
                              }
                              else{
                                alert("localstorage not cleared");
                              }

                          }
                });

        });
```

In controller try like this, it may work. it worked for me

```
public function send_to_staff(){

    $staff_id=$this->input->post('staff_id');
    $staff_id=json_encode($staff_id); //converting to json
    $membersids[]= $this->input->post('members_id');
    $members_id=json_encode($membersids);  //converting to json

    if($staff_id !==''){  
        $data['staff_id']=$staff_id;
        $data['members_id']=$members_id;
         $inserted=$this->db->insert('ag_matched_members',$data); //insert query
        if($inserted == true){
            echo true; //returns true
        }
        else
        {
            echo false;  //returns false
        }

    }

}
```